# Read command skip subsequent instructions in HEREDOC - Bash + Docker

Tags: bash, docker

I'm having trouble with a case that I see as a bug in how the shell or bash works, in which running a non interactive command supplied from a heredoc (maybe from a file too, I haven't tested) and a `read` (or similar) command in the heredoc, causes the code after a `read` command to be **ignored**, and the execution to ends **without errors**, executing the commands **after** the command that runs the heredoc.

More specifically, I'm running code in a docker container that acts as a toolbox for several linux utilities, and this problem causes the code to not be actually safe in the sense that I can't trust that it will happen as I expect.

A sample of the problem can be seen bellow:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

echo "before outside" >&2

docker run --rm -i ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash <<-SHELL
    set -eou pipefail
    echo "before inside" >&2
    read 'var'
    echo "after inside" >&2
SHELL

echo "after outside" >&2
```

I would expected that the above code either runs all the echoes and ends successfully, or gives an error in the `read` command and ends with an error.

Unfortunately, the output of the above code is:

```bash
before outside
before inside
after outside
```

**It basically ignored what was after the `read` command**, maybe because it has a `read` instruction in a command that doesn't allocate a pseudo-tty (`docker run -it` allocates a pseudo-tty, but can't run the above code, because of the heredoc that is piped to the command, instead it gives the error: `the input device is not a TTY`).

If I remove the 2 `set -eou pipefail` I have the same problem, even using `read 'var' ||:`, so I don't think it's related to (one of the *gotchas* of) `set -e`.

An example of an expected result is as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

echo "before outside" >&2

docker run --rm -i ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash <<-SHELL
    set -eou pipefail
    echo "before inside" >&2
    unknow_command error ||:
    echo "after inside" >&2
SHELL

echo "after outside" >&2
```

Which ends succesfully and prints:

```bash
before outside
before inside
/bin/bash: line 3: unknow_command: command not found
after inside
after outside
```

Or:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

echo "before outside" >&2

docker run --rm -i ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash <<-SHELL
    set -eou pipefail
    echo "before inside" >&2
    unknow_command error
    echo "after inside" >&2
SHELL

echo "after outside" >&2
```

Which ends with an error and prints:

```bash
before outside
before inside
/bin/bash: line 3: unknow_command: command not found
```

For me it would be ok if the `read` command was just skipped (with an empty value as input, for example) and all commands after were executed, even the ones in the heredoc, or that it gives an error and stops the execution immediatelly (if I don't ignore the error in the docker command).

The above was just an example, in a real case it can be much worse because the `read` (or similar) command may not be called directly, but inside a command, and only under some conditions. For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

docker run --rm -i my_mysql /bin/bash <<-SHELL
    set -eou pipefail
    some_important_command_1
    mysql -u "$user" -p "$pass" -e "some sql command"
    some_important_command_2
SHELL

some_important_command_after_2
```

The above code may seem fine, but if the password is empty, it will try to read from stdin, causing the problem in the first example, skipping `some_important_command_2`, but running `some_important_command_after_2` that should run only after `some_important_command_2`.

The above mysql example was also just an example, I can verify in this case if the password is empty and handle it. **The real problem is that I can't determine if this problem can happen inside a code and I see no safe way to avoid it**, aside from stopping the use of the docker toolbox container and install all utilities and other stuff inside all hosts, and keeping them up-to-date (instead of just keeping the container image up-to-date). It also won't work for commands that run speciffically in services inside conttainers (like the mysql example above).

**Someone has a solution for the above problem?** A solution that **is not specific** to the examples I gave, but a general approach that can solve **this type of bug** (either by completing successfully, executing all commands, or giving an error and stopping all subsequent commands).

**Update:**

Adding `declare -p var` after `echo "after inside"` outputs:

```
before outside
before inside
declare -- var="echo \"after inside\" >&2"
after outside
```

I guess that the read command ends up reading from the heredoc as @muru pointed in the comments. I can also see it if I add `echo "var=\$var"` after `echo "after inside"`, which prints: `var=echo "after inside" >&2`. So now I have to see a way to skip those reads from the heredoc itself.

Comment: Put an `declare -p var` after `echo "after inside"` and see what happens.

Comment: @muru Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, the read command ended up reading the next command of the heredoc (because the heredoc is the input of the docker command, but in this case ended up being input for the read command inside it). Now I have to figure out how to avoid it (supplying an empty string and continuing the execution, or giving an error and stopping it, both approachs should be fine in such cases, but not the way it's now).

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do what you were doing at all. It costs nothing to put the commands in a script, and then do `docker run ... -v /path/to/script:/my-script ... /bin/bash /my-script`.

Comment: @muru Actually I thought about that too, but I use these commands in several files and I would need to remove these parts in every case and put them in a separate location, which could also make the code harder to read (because the commands would be separated in different places, although in some cases it could actually be better). Not the end of the world, but I would like to avoid to make major changes if I could avoid this problem. If I can't find a better approach, I think I will go in that direction (it would be safer).

Comment: You could use heredocs to put the contents in a temp file, and use that temp as the script in the container. Only significant change is you'd need to clean up the temp file in your scripts.